# Controlling the left-right alignment of columns in Files / Nautilus in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: nautilus

I'm migrating from Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.10 and there's one aspect of the file explorer that I don't like. Specifically, I would like to retain the left alignment of the columns if possible.

This is what it looked like on 15.10:

> [image]
>
> Files 3.14.2

This is what the default looks like on 16.10:

> [image]
>
> Files 3.20.3

Note that the date is all the way over to the right end of the window. I find this very off-putting, and I want that information where I can see it, not all the way over elsewheres. Is there some way to control this?

Comment: Why not just narrowing the "Modified - Time" column?

Comment: Narrowing from the left defeats the purpose, and there is no way to narrow it from the right.

Answer (score 2):

In a Nautilus file manager window, showing in list mode, right-click on the **Name** column title and add ANY column AFTER the **Modified-Time** column. Then you can grab the Modified-Time column right width handle and move it to the desired column width. Then right-click on the **Name** column title again, and remove the extra column that you no longer need.

Or, using the same method to select/deselect columns, enable **Modified** and disable **Modified-Time**.

Comment: @mchid It's probably because they've updated Nautilus since 16.10. You might try another File Manager.

Comment: Nemo has the same problem on 18.04. However, I just downgraded to the Xenial version of Nautilus and it works fine now. Instead of installing it, I just extracted the deb and am running the `./usr/bin/naurilus` file locally. I had to edit my `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.nautilus.gschema.xml` file and download some missing libs but it works.

Comment: @mchid you might look at Thunar.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, Thunar doesn't have the searching capabilities that Nemo and Nautils have.

Comment: @mchid have you looked at PCMan (pcmanfm) file manager?

Comment: I was looking at some of the bug reports and developer screenshots earlier and one of the screenshots showed pcmanfm using the correct alignment as a comparison but they didn't say the name so I didn't know what it was. Thanks!